# Delete all unattached Google Persistent Disks in a project

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

In GKE, the `Reclaim Policy` of my `PersistentVolume` is set to `Retain`, in order to prevent unintentional data removal. However, sometimes, after the deletion of some `PersistentVolumes`, I'd like to remove the associated `Google Persistent Disks` manually. Deleting the `Google Persistent Disks` using the web UI (i.e. Google Cloud Console) is time-consuming, that's why I'd like to use a  `gcloud` command to remove all `Google Persistent Disks` that are not attached to a GCP VM instance. Could somebody please provide me this command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one should work:

```
gcloud compute disks delete $(gcloud compute disks list --filter="-users:*" --format "value(uri())")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **gcloud compute disks delete** command in cloud shell to delete all the disks that are not attached in a gcp vm instance.

gcloud compute disks delete DISK_NAME [DISK_NAME …] [--region=REGION     | --zone=ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]

you can provide disknames through this command to delete them.

[disk delete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/delete)

Comment: Thanks! However I'd like to get the accurate one-liner which exactly does what I want. I.e. only delete unattached volumes.

Answer (score 1):

The link that @sandeep-mohanty includes suggests that **only** non-attached disks are deleted by the command.

Assuming (!) that to be true (check before you delete), you can enumerate a project's disks and then delete the (not attached) disks with:

```sh
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]

# Get PAIRS (NAME,ZONE) for all disk in ${PROJECT}
# Using CSV  (e.g. my-disk,my-zone) enables IFS parsing (below)
PAIRS=$(\
  gcloud compute disks list \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="csv[no-heading](name,zone.scope())")

# Iterate over the PAIRS
for PAIR in ${PAIRS}
do
  # Extract values of NAME,ZONE from PAIR
  IFS=, read NAME ZONE <<< ${PAIR}
  # Describe
  printf "Attempting to delete disk: %s [%s]\n" ${NAME} ${ZONE}
  # Deleting a disks should only succeed if not attached
  gcloud compute disks delete ${NAME} \
  --zone=${ZONE} \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --quiet
done
```

> **NOTE** In the unlikely event that Google changes the semantics of `gcloud compute disks delete` to delete **attached** disks, this script will delete every disk in the project.

Comment: Trying to delete an attached disks will return following error: `gcloud compute disks delete projects/qserv-int-8069/zones/us-central1-c/disks/gke-qserv-int-czar-pool-01ed-d0f9ba57-68en ...
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.disks.delete) Could not fetch resource:
 - The disk resource 'projects/qserv-int-8069/zones/us-central1-c/disks/gke-qserv-int-czar-pool-01ed-d0f9ba57-68en' is already being used by 'projects/qserv-int-8069/zones/us-central1-c/instances/gke-qserv-int-czar-pool-01ed-d0f9ba57-68en'
`. I'd like to get a script which does not try to delete attached disk in order to avoid this error.